# Local storage used with pagination

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have multiple pages of checkboxes, and I need to store these values within local storage so that I can submit all of the checked checkboxes in a form, e.g.

```
Page 1:
- Checkbox 1: checked
- Checkbox 2: unchecked
- Checkbox 3: unchecked

Page 2:
- Checkbox 1: unchecked
- Checkbox 2: checked
- Checkbox 3: checked

Form submission:
- Page 1 Checkbox 1 Value
- Page 2 Checkbox 2 Value
- Page 2 Checkbox 3 Value
```

My problem arises when the user selects a checkbox on page 1, and then navigates to page 2 and selects another checkbox. I am currently storing the checkbox values, however when I navigate to page to another page, the local storage values are overwritten with the new set of checkbox values. This is because I was previously storing them in the same local storage item.

I have worked around this by storing the checkboxes in different local storage items by adding the current page number to the name of the local storage item, like so:

```
// Get current page number
var pageNumber = {{ pageNumber }};

// Retrieve local storage
var brochureArrs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('brochureArrs' + pageNumber));
```

The issue with the above is when it comes to retrieving the info so that I can submit it through a form, as I need to combine an infinite number of local storage items for the infinite number of pages. How therefore do I loop through each of the local storage items that start with `brochureArrs` so that I can combine them into one?

Apologies for the possibly long-winded explanation to a potentially simple problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact scenario, but if you are talking about a paginated list of data, where each checkbox represents an item, I would argue it's much preferable to submit a list of unique ID:s, rather than a value derived from their relative position in the list. I.e. if "item 20" is selected, store `20`, not `Page 2 Item 10`, because a) you don't have that same problem with overwrites, and b) that saves you problems in the future when you implement custom sorting and filtering, and no longer can rely on list position.

If your scenario is different, however, using page and list index may of course make sense. So for a more straight forward answer, you can easily enumerate all storage items that starts with `borchureArrs` by using `Object.keys`:

```
var pageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.indexOf('brochureArrs') === 0);
```

This will yield a list of all keys in `localStorage`that start with `brochureArrs`. If the value of those keys are all arrays, you could combine them like so:

```
var values = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], pageKeys.map(key => JSON.parse(localStorage[key])));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqyd5sw7/)

Comment: You are a genius!  My scenario was indeed different from what you mention in the first part of your answer, but the snippets below managed to get me on track and all is working well now :)